# React native voice isn't detecting my voice

Tags: react-native, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, react-native-voice

I'm encountering an issue with React Native Voice where it's not detecting my voice, specifically, the onSpeechResults callback is not getting called. Instead, I'm receiving the following warnings:

WARN `new NativeEventEmitter()` was called with a non-null argument without the required `addListener` method.
WARN `new NativeEventEmitter()` was called with a non-null argument without the required `removeListeners` method.

I haven't linked my app to React Native Voice explicitly, as I've read that for newer versions of React Native, this should be done automatically.

Has anyone else experienced this issue? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I've checked that other React Native Voice functions like isAvailable and onSpeechStart are being called properly.

Comment: copy and run this example https://github.com/react-native-voice/voice/blob/master/example/src/VoiceTestFuncComp.tsx